# Django cannot be installed on virtual environment. (permission)

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I like to install django on virtual-env I get the following error.

I am just curios why it is trying to change things under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django.

Thank you in advance. Your help is much appreciated and voted.

Cheers,

```
(env) mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/work/django/estore$ pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-1.10.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: django
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling pip from bin folder of the env you create see if that works (below). Did you define an alias for pip command.

```
$ ./env/bin/pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give write privileges for all users to the directory where virtual environment is located.

```
sudo chmod -R o+rwx /env
```

After that you can use pip without sodu.